# Concise Option extraction with dependencies

Tags: rust

I have a function that needs to use the values contained in 4 different Options. Most values are necessary to access what's in the next Option (not strictly all of them, though), so its not as simple as something like `Some(Some(Some(Some(foo)))`.

The goal of my function is to use all of the options to get the final piece of data and return that data (as an Option itself). If any of the Options is `None`, the function should return `None`. The code I've implemented is correct and works, but the multitude of nested `if let` statements is a red flag to me. The version using guards is a significant improvement, imo. This still feels clumsy compared to `Result`'s `?` operator, which lets you bail out of a several commands very concisely.

```
struct Foo {
    mynames: Option<Vec<String>>,
    myidxs: Vec<Option<usize>>,
}

impl Foo {
    /// Get the name at index i where i is stored in myidxs[0]
    /// If any option is None, return None
    fn get_name_for_first_index(&self) -> Option<String> {
        if let Some(first_elem) = self.myidxs.first() {
            if let Some(idx) = first_elem {
                if let Some(names) = &self.mynames {
                    if let Some(name) = names.get(*idx) {
                        return Some(name.to_string())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        None
    }
    
    // cleaner
    fn get_name_for_first_index_guards(&self) -> Option<String> {
        let Some(Some(idx)) = self.myidxs.first() else {return None};
        let Some(names) = &self.mynames else {return None};
        let Some(name) = names.get(*idx) else {return None};
        Some(name.to_string())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo{
        mynames: Some(vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string()]),
        myidxs: vec![Some(1), Some(4)]
    };
    
    println!("{}", f.get_name_for_first_index_guards().unwrap());
}
```

I would certainly appreciate any other feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The try operator `?` isn't an operator on results, it works on anything that implements [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) including `Option`, the type you `?` on just has to be compatible with the return type of the function. So you can just use it:

```rust
    fn get_name_for_first_index(&self) -> Option<String> {
        let idx = self.myidxs.first()?.as_ref()?;
        let names = self.mynames.as_ref()?;
        let name = names.get(*idx)?;
        Some(name.to_string())
    }
```

Though you have to insert some `as_ref` calls to convert `&Option<T>` to `Option<&T>` because `?` does not work for `&Option`s.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the `?` behavior. Following your link eventually led me [here in the rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#where-the--operator-can-be-used) with a discussion on using `?` with `Option`.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing cafce25's answer, both Option and Result also have a suite of monadic combinators e.g.

```
fn get_name_for_first_index(&self) -> Option<String> {
    self.myidxs.first()
        // somewhat complex bit because of the double option,
        // would be simpler with a `?` but we're not doing that
        // here
        .map(Option::as_ref)
        .flatten()
        .zip(self.mynames.as_ref())
        .and_then(|(&idx, names)| names.get(idx))
        .map(|n| n.to_string())
}
```

Comment: you could replace `.map(Option::as_ref).flatten()` with `.and_then(Option::as_ref)`